# How complex should a presentational component be before making it smart?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As I see it, I could make my entire app a presentational/dumb component and then have a single container component pass the appropriate props.

On the other extreme, I could make every single component smart.

So, is there a rule of thumb to decide when to make your presentational component smart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) by Dan Abramov:

> ### When to Introduce Containers?
>
> I suggest you to start building your app with just presentational components first. Eventually you’ll realize that you are passing too many props down the intermediate components. When you notice that some components don’t use the props they receive but merely forward them down and you have to rewire all those intermediate components any time the children need more data, it’s a good time to introduce some container components. This way you can get the data and the behavior props to the leaf components without burdening the unrelated components in the middle of the tree.
>
> ... This is an ongoing process of refactoring so don’t try to get it right the first time.

---

I would argue that there should be a nice balance between the size/complexity of the app and the number of smart components (containers).

**Consider introducing a container when:**

1. The hierarchy becomes too deep and passing props around becomes a hassle.
2. It is likely that an entire feature (UI + data mapping) will be moved/re-used across the app.
3. There's a need to encapsulate a feature for reasons such as the above or any other (versioning, security, lazy-loading etc.)
4. You identify unnecessary updates as a result of data mapping.

**On the other hand, consider sharing a container when:**

1. Multiple components use data of the same nature and form a single unit that might be considered a "feature".
2. Mapping (`mapStateToProps`/`mapDispatchToProps`) becomes repetitive amongst multiple proximate components.

Also, keep in mind that refactoring might be necessary as your app evolves.